# Jndi value cant support dots

Tags: jboss, jndi, jboss-cli

I am trying to declare a new JNDI with the tool jboss-cli.sh.

This is my basic instruction:

/subsystem=naming/binding=java:/comp/env/config/rutaLogback:add(value="/var/opt/logback.xml",binding-type=simple)

The problem is that my value has a dot (value="/var/opt/logback.xml") and when I execute it , the value shown is only "xml" instead of the complete value that I wrote in the instruction.

I tried to escape the dot by many different ways.

```
:add(value="/var/opt/logback\.xml",binding-type=simple)
:add(value="/var/opt/logback\\.xml",binding-type=simple)
:add(value="/var/opt/logback\\\.xml",binding-type=simple)
:add(value="/var/opt/logback&#046;xml",binding-type=simple)
```

Etc...

But it doesn`t work..

I expect to obtain the value /var/opt/logback.xml in the JNDI when i look that in the server console.

Comment: which jboss version are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce on EAP 7.1 ; I need to put the JDNI path between quotes because of the `/` it contains, but there's no problem with the `.` in the value, which is properly replicated into the XML configuration.

Comment: @Aaron Your answer made me watch the value in the standalone.xml and there the value is OK!! The problem seems to be only with the admin console viewer of the JBOSS! Thank you

Comment: Good to know ! If you're on an up-to-date install and have a support contract with RedHat it'd be a good idea to report the bug still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

I watch the value in the standalone.xml and there the value is OK!! The problem seems to be only with the viewer of the admin console of the JBOSS and it doesn`t matter!